# using join tables vs a one way lookup

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

We will store comments for several objects in our database for example Customer, Product, Order, etc. Each entry can have multiple comments. For primary keys, we will go with GUIDs. Traditionally, we would do a join tables for the above such as Customer_Comment, Order_comment, Product_Comment, etc.

Since we will always be looking up comments from the Order or Customer or Product, we only need a one-way lookup. We will never need to lookup which Entity a comment belongs to, we only need to load comments for a particular entity. There was a suggestion that instead of using Join tables, we just have a LinkId field on Comment table which records Guids of all the entities such as Customer Id, or Product Id. Then, we can just look up all the comments that belong to a particular entity and since the Guids are unique, there won't be any conflicts.

I am wondering if there are any downsides to using this sort of architecture in terms of database storage and lookup efficiency. Also we will only be using Entity Framework and probably not querying the Db directly. What sort of issues we will have with this approach in that regard?

EDIT: Comment table: ID(guid), Text, LinkId(Guid). LinkId will link to entities such as Customer, Product, etc.

Comment: How did/do you associate the comment to the object/entity prior to adding the GUID field is there another unique ID?

Comment: the comment will only go in if the entity exists. Then the comment LinkId field will point to the Entity Id

Comment: `extra field on Comment table which records Guids of all the entities such as Customer Id, or Product Id. ` don't you already have `linkid` for this?

Comment: that IS the LinkId

Comment: Even if Guids are unique, you won't be able to setup relationship in EF, hence the querying should be with manual joins.

Comment: "There was a suggestion that instead of using Join tables, we just have a LinkId field on Comment table which records Guids of all the entities " Whoever made this suggestion does not seem to understand or be advocate of (the power) RDBMS 
If you will only be doing a look-up you don't need to worry about the EF limitations just write a line query or stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you have classes like Customer, Product, Order, etc. And you have a one-to-many relationship between these and Comments: every Customer has zero or more Comments, every Comment belongs to exactly one Customer.

One of the problems is that the tables you plan to use will lose your database normalization. Instead of CustomerComments, ProductComments and OrderComments, you plan to use Comments with one foreign key, to sometimes the Customer table, sometimes the Product table, etc.

I think it is wise to reconsider if this is what you really want. In your current version all Comments have the same layout, but what if in future versions you want a CustomerComment to be different than a ProductComment?

Besides, because you put all Comments in one table, all queries will be slower. It will be possible to delete a Customer without deleting his Comments, leaving you with Comments that don't belong to anything. In a properly normalized database this is impossible, your database management system will take care that every foreign key points to something.

So my Advise would be to create a table with CustomerComments, one with ProductComments etc. All these table aggregate the Comments class and have a foreign key to the proper Customer / Product etc. If you really want, you could inherit the classes from Comments, but I seldom see any benefit from this.

So my proposal would be:

```
class Comment
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
    ...
}

class Customer
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}

    // every Customer has zero or more Comments (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerComment> Comments {get; set;}

    ... // other Customer properties
}

class CustomerComment
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}

    // every CustomerComment belongs to exactly one Customer using foreign key
    public Guid CustomerId {get; set;}
    public virtual Customer Customer {get; set;}

    public Comment Comment {get; set;}
    ... // free to add other properties in future versioins,
        // without disturbing ProductComments
}
```

Similar classes for Product and ProductComment.

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Product> Products {get; set;}

    public DbSet<CustomerComment> CustomerComments {get; set;}
    public DbSet<ProductComment> ProductComments {get; set;}
}
```

The nice thing is that if you have a CustomerId it is faster to get the Comments of the Customer with this Id:

```
var commentsOfCustomerWithId = myDbContext.CustomerComments
    .Where(customerComment => customerComment.CustomerId == CustomerId)
    .Select(customerComment => Comment);
```

And the following is an even nicer feature of entity framework. If you have a CustomerId and you want the "Customer with his Comments" you don't need to do a join:

```
var customerWithHisComments = myDbContext.Customers
   .Where(customer => customer.Id == customerId)
   .Select(customer => new
   {
       // select only the properties you plan to use:
       Name = customer.Name,
       Address = customer.Address,
       ...

       Comments = customer.Comments.Select(comment => new
       {
           // again select only the comment properties you plan to use:
           Text = comment.Text,
           Category = comment.Category,
           ...
       })
       .ToList(),
   })
   .SingleOrDefault();
```

The nice thing is that even if this Customer has no Comments, you get a properly filled (empty) list with Comments.

The transfer of data from the database to your local machine is one of the slower parts. Hence it is always wise to only select the properties that you  plan to use, instead of selecting complete items. For instance, if the Customer with Id 100 has 400 Comments, then all these 400 Comments will have a CustomerId of 100. If you transfer all properties of this Customer with all his Comments you'll transfer the number 100 more than 400 times, while you might probably not even use it, or maybe only once (because you'll know they all have the same value)

Comment: thanks. rethinking the architecture in terms of the domain really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Having a single table for comments will introduce difficulties in configuring EF relationships. So you better stick with separate comments table per entity.

Comment: yeah but there can be multiple comments per entry, so I'm not sure how we can store comments in same table.

Comment: Join tables, traditionally.